# excel VBA - searching single column for a range of values and selecting the rows the values are in

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

Column A has numerical values or strings in each cell, values of 0 - 15000 are listed, i need to find and select each row containing numerical values and add a border to the top of the row.

Putting a border on top of each cell in the row was easy, but trying to search the column for numerical values has me stumped.

any help would be great.

Comment: Conditional formatting is your answer.  You can set any style, including borders, based on value.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub topHeavy()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            With Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey gary, i was wondering would it be possible to also do the same search but look up certain numbers and add a empty row. for example search for numbers 1-10 add a empty row after 10, search for number 11-50 and add an empty row, etc...

Comment: just use generic numbers, so 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50. just need 5 sets.

Comment: i'm trying to seperate, for example ID's. So in the column i have the list of numbers in numerical order; 1-50. lets say i want to seperate these numbers by adding another empty row, and seperating by 1-10, 11-15, 16-25, etc... and adds an empty row after 10, 15, 25.